# Turning a definition in English to one using quantifiers questions. Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, logic, quantifiers

so the book im studying defines adherent points in the following way.

> Let $X$ be a subset of $R$, and let $x \in R$ We say that $x$ is an adherent point  to $X$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $y\in X$ which is $\epsilon-close$ to $x$ (i.e $|x-y|\leq\epsilon$)

so in terms of quantifiers which one does it go along with is it either:

> $\forall\epsilon >0\exists y$ $( y\in X  \rightarrow |x-y| \leq \epsilon$

or is it

> $\forall\epsilon >0\exists y$ $( y\in X \land |x-y| \leq \epsilon)$

since i am trying to negate them in which case the first one becomes

> $\exists\epsilon >0\forall y$ $( y\in X \land |x-y| > \epsilon)$

and the second becomes

> $\exists\epsilon >0\forall y$ $( y\notin X \lor |x-y| > \epsilon)$

which seems strange please any thoughts? thank you so much!

Comment: what does that mean? is it an implication or a intersection?

Comment: It is the one with the $\wedge$ because the one with the implication is always true if $X \not = R$. You just need to take any $y \in R \setminus X$ and the implication would be true.

Comment: but the negation of that one "$\exists\epsilon >0\forall y$ $( y\notin X \lor |x-y| > \epsilon)$"
seems strange in practise a point is not adherent iff for all y in X we have $|x-y| > \epsilon$ in other words every y in X does not satisfy the inequality. Which says something different than the formal one.

Comment: The negation tells you that if $x$ is not an adherent point of $X$, then there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for every $y \in R$ you have that $y$ is not an element of $X$ or $|x-y|> \epsilon$. For that fixed $\epsilon$, you have that for every $y$ one of them must be true. So, if you take any $y  \in X$ you would have that $|x-y|>\epsilon$. That is, you can fix a distance $\epsilon$ such that every element in $X$ is further from $x$ that $\epsilon$.

Comment: Observe that the definition is telling you that for every $\epsilon$, you have a $y \in X$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $x$. The negation of that is precisely what you say, that there exists at least one $\epsilon$ such that no $y$ in $X$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$.

Comment: ahh i see, since if any  y is in X this forces |x-y| > $\epsilon$ to be true (by properties of the "or" connective)  am i thinking correcting like you said?

Comment: That's it, it is because of the definition of "or" in mathematics ;)

Comment: thank you so much, sometimes dealing with these properties can be strange! Thank you thank you.

Comment: oh it is just the last part of the negation with the blank in between $y \in X$ and $|x-y| > \epsilon$ seems strange.

Comment: right so when we negate it we get: $\forall y (y \notin X \lor P(y) \equiv \forall y \in X ~P(y)$ is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These formalisations of the given definition are all correct (and logically equivalent): \begin{gather}\forall\epsilon \;\Big(\epsilon >0  → \exists y\; \big(y\in X ∧ |x-y| \leq \epsilon\big)\Big),\tag1\\
\forall\epsilon {>}0\;\exists y{\in} X \quad |x-y| \leq \epsilon,\tag2\\
\forall\epsilon \;\exists y \;\Big(\epsilon >0  → \big(y\in X ∧ |x-y| \leq \epsilon\big)\Big).\tag3\end{gather}

Statement $(2)$ is an abbreviation of statement $(1).$ Its negation is $$∃\epsilon {>}0\;∀y{\in} X \quad |x-y| > \epsilon.$$

---

**Addendum** (from the comments)

After your edit, your second and fourth formalisations are indeed correct.

> the blank in between y∈X and |x−y|>ϵ seems strange.

I widened the gap/spacing merely for readability. Do note that $$∃y{∈}X\;P(y)\tag A$$ is just a more succinct way of writing $$∃y\;\Big(y∈X\land P(y)\Big).\tag B$$

> right so when we negate it we get $$\forall y (y \notin X \lor P(y)) \equiv \forall y \in X ~P(y);$$ is that correct?

I think you meant to write
$$\forall y\;(y \notin X \lor ¬P(y))$$ and $$\forall y{\in}X\;¬P(y)$$ instead, which are indeed the correct (and logically equivalent) negations of $(B)$ and $(A).$

Comment: The negation of these statements is also equivalent to $\exists \epsilon>0 \forall y (y \not \in X \vee |x-y|>\epsilon)$ as JCAL stated in his answer.